Why do receptor tyrosine kinases undergo constitutive endocytosis?
I am reading a journal paper about the endocytosis of receptor tyrosine kinases. I have a question about the following statement:

At the cell surface RTKs undergo constitutive endocytosis
(internalization) at a rate similar to that of other integral membrane
proteins. Constitutive internalization of RTKs is much slower than
their constitutive recycling from endosomes back to the cell surface.
Therefore, RTKs are accumulated at the cell surface, which allows
maximal accessibility to extracellular ligands.

I know that RTKs get endocytosed upon binding of their ligand and either get targeted for lysosomal degradation or get recycled back to the cell surface. Lysosomal degradation of the receptor is a mechanism to downregulate levels of the receptor and control the strength/duration of the signaling.
However, what is the purpose of constitutive endocytosis of RTKs? Further, does this occur even if the ligand is not bound to the receptor?
